# JavaScript Automated Iframe Creation

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to know how I can automatically create Iframes depending on how many html files are in a directory. Say I have `1.html` and `2.html` in a sub directory of where `main.html` is. I want to automatically create 2 Iframes (in `main.html`), one showing `1.html` and the other showing `2.html`. Btw, if you couldn't tell, `2.html` and `1.html` are local files

Comment: where does the list of files come from?

Comment: It is in a sub-directory of where my html file is.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/images-folder-on-server/",
    success: function (data) {
        var file_count = $(data).length();
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
           appendIframe(value);
        });
    }
});

function appendIframe( file)
{
   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.src = file;
   iframe.style.width = "100px";
   iframe.style.height = "100px";
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a ajax-call to server to get the list of files in a directory

```
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
   //iterate the list and call addIframe( src ) for each of them 
};
httpRequest.open('GET', "listFilesInDirectory");
httpRequest.send();
```

this is what addIframe look like

```
function addIframe( src )
{
   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.src = src;
   iframe.style.width = "640px";
   iframe.style.height = "px";
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}

addIframe( "subdir/1.html" );
addIframe( "subdir/2.html" );
```

Comment: Any way to get rid of                                                                   `addIframe( "subdir/1.html" );
addIframe( "subdir/2.html" );`    Like automate that, I'm planning on having lots of files

Comment: @DenverP. yes, you need to create a service which will give you a list of files in the directory.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the list of files?

Comment: @DenverP. that will depend on what you server side language is.

Comment: At the moment I'm just local, so... no server. All my code is JS

Comment: @DenverP. Javascript is running in your browser, it is not running on your server. So without server side call you cannot fetch the list of files.

Comment: Thanks, helped me out lots

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is not how to create iFrame using Javascript but is to count the files using it. I suggest to create ajax request to a server side language to count the number of files then you can use that number to create iFrame element using jQuery. You can use the below code written in `PHP` as a server side script:-

```
<?php
function getNoFiles(){
    $i = 0;
    $dir = 'yourHTMLDirectory/';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
            if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file))
                $i++;
        }
    }
echo $i;
  }

?>
```

You can use such jQuery simple code for your creation under simple loop with the limit of the gotten count from PHP code.

```
$('<your iframe tag></iframe>').appendTo('your div or area class or id');
```